# Programatically save music to the Zune hub in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, zune

Is it possible to programmatically save (music) files to the Zune hub in windows phone 7?

For instance, I've created a recording app and want to be able to push the saved recordings to the Zune hub to be part of my audio collection.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked at integrating with the [Music and Videos hub](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769558%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that.

There are other types of integration available, though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769558(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: I've read this article before asking, but wanted to make sure there's no deeper way of integration. Thanks anyawy!